# "Parameter 'id' implicitly has an 'any' type." when no default value given

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a class with a constructor that takes an argument:

```js
class Foo {
  id: string;

  constructor(id: string) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

The above code gives me an error:

```
ERROR in /home/me/my-project/resources/js/app.ts
./resources/js/app.ts 4:16-18
[tsl] ERROR in /home/me/my-project/resources/js/app.ts(4,17)
      TS7006: Parameter 'id' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

If I provide a default value to the parameter, I don't get an error:

```js
class Foo {
  id: string;

  constructor(id: string = '') {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell, both of these should be valid TypeScript. I'm using Laravel Mix 6.0.48 and TypeScript 4.7.3. My `tsconfig.json` is as follows:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "resources/js",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [ "*" ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "resources/**/*.ts",
    "resources/**/*.d.ts",
    "resources/**/*.tsx",
    "resources/**/*.vue"
  ]
}
```

Edit: I've put together a gist with a simplified example: https://gist.github.com/mrchimp/ccb334c626a348d367a30c3126043384

Comment: What do you have in your `app.ts`?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, please share your `app.ts`.

Comment: Literally just my example code above. Nothing else.

Comment: It makes no sense !

Comment: Right?! I tried changing `"target":"esnext"` to `es6` instead but then I get an additional error: `TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Foo'.` ...which also makes no sense.

Comment: I've added a gist with a simplified example.

Comment: Do you have an `private` ou `public` keyword in your constructor's paramters  ?

Comment: No. It's just as I've written above. I think it must have something to do with the tsconfig or Webpack/Mix setup as the code seems fine when I try it on the typescript playground.